# Where to find joomla content source files

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, resource-files

I'm having this website on joomla framework http://carhitz.com/
I want to add some new buttons and new divs to different pages of my website but I can't find the source code of individual pages. I know that they're in the components folder with something like com_(something) but I really can't figure out which component file points to which page.
For eg: I want to find the php file containing the content of the following link:

http://carhitz.com/lighting-gallery

But I can't find that component or whatever file that is used to generate all those sculpture gallery items. DOes anyone have an idea where can I find them?
I'm using hexeris theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla! does not work like pages in some folder, the content is generated by menu items, components or modules.

In your example, it seems that you are using a component called *RokGallery*, so, find this component in the main menu  **Components** in the back-end of your site.

If you need change something in this component, you need an **override**, here you have the
 step by step: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

---

Also you can check this useful guides:

- [Beginners Guide to Joomla!](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Beginners)
- [Joomla Administrators](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Administrators)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I still can't find the exact file to edit. I found com_RokGallery but I'm still stuck with a bunch of files not sure what they point to. 

I came across this path 

/components/com_rokgallery/views/detail/tmpl

And there I have folders like "detail","gallery" but they have nothing of interest.. How would I know which file to override?

Answer (score 1):

Folder to show content of com_content: `yourhost\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`

But I suggest best way to change a custom page is add a custom module in backend -> extensions ->module and assign the module to menu

Answer (score 0):

Joomla framework is based on MVC (Model View Controller). Command goes from User->Controller->Model(Database)->Views. If you disable sef url in global configuration you will find links like this. http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_example&view=content&id=7. This means the component is com_example which you can find inside components folder. It calls the controller which redirects to the model and then model redirects to views folder. Inside views there is tmp folder and inside this there is a default.php file which is template for the view. The variables passed to default.php is from views.php file. If you check this link you will find more details https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component .

Comment: I turned of sef url from global configuration but the links are still showing the same way... :(

Comment: Did you switched off all 4 sef options and did you clear the cache?

Comment: all 4? which ones? Can u tell me where can I find them?

Comment: heck this link https://weeblr.com/media/com_wbdoc/display/products.sh404sef/4/images/getting-started/sh404sef-getting-started-joomla-add-suffix.png

Comment: yeah, I did all 4, still not working. You can chek the website links yourself. It's not changing

Comment: Are you using any sef components like sh404sef or ace sef etc? And did you clear the cache?

Comment: There is no need to uninstall it in a live site. My intention was to give an idea how joomla works. You can install a new joomla in localhost and do all testing. For this site i recommend to revert back the global configuration settigs. Install Akeeba backup. Take backup of your entire site. Install the backup in your localhost and then play with it to know more about joomla.

Comment: I have another website, and the links appear like this http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_example&view=content&id=7

Even though the sef option is turned on.
Are you talking about clearing my browser cache to take effect?

And this link is to a test server, it's not live website. I've copied it to my sever

Comment: yes sometimes the template is cached. And if you are using any sef components then they may override your joomla settings.

Comment: So if thats the case, then it should work on another browser or even you can see the changes.

Comment: Cached files are also stored in server.